# Accessing a variable outside of a while loop, Python

Tags: python, sockets, variables, loops, while-loop

I'm writing a Python script to fetch data from a specific port.
So I got a while loop that fetches my data as long as the port is open.
In this while loop I'm adding up a variable, lets call it `foo1`.
When the time is up, I don't want to fetch any more data.

So the pseudocode would look like the following:

```
foo1 = 0

try:

   while True:
       fetch data
       foo1 = foo1 + 500

       if time up:
           break

finally:
    close socket

print foo1
```

Inside of my while loop `foo1` adds up correctly. But outside of the loop
`foo1` is always zero. Do you have any idea?

Just exchange **foo1** with **coh0**
edit:

```
import re

coh = [0]
nachricht = ' S="0" '
coh0 = 0
time = 0
try:
    while True:
        time += 1
        coh = re.findall(r'\bS="\d"', nachricht)
        coh_value = re.findall(r'\d', coh[0])  

        if coh:
            if int(coh_value[0]) == 0:
                coh0 = int(coh0) + 500
                print coh0


        if time == 10:        
            coh0 = int((int(coh0)/500)/120)

            print "Here coh0 is zero again",int(coh0)
            break
finally:
    pass

print "Here coh0 is zero again",int(coh0)
```

Comment: Your example doesn't work as you reference `foo1` before it exists. Please give a simple, self contained, **working** example.

Comment: If your fetching and addition portion is inside a function, ensure that you return your value once you're done.

Comment: Don't just dump your code, give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes, I corrected it. Didnt know what SSCE was, sorry :)

Comment: That's still far too much. You need to create the simplest possible code that shows your problem. Please read the link I have given through, and then update your question.

Comment: Is it better now ?
ps: its not self-contained, but I think you get the problem.

Comment: No, it needs to run as it is, this does not. It needs to be self-contained. If you are not willing to put in the effort to make a minimal example then why should others help you? You make it harder for them, and you miss out on potentially solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```py
coh0 = int((int(coh0)/500)/120)
```

effectively performs an integer division by 60000 – it could be equivalently written as

```py
coh0 //= 60000
```

If `coh0` happens to be less than 60000 before executing this line, it will be 0 afterwards.

> Inside of my while loop `foo1` adds up correctly. But outside of the loop `foo1` is always zero.

This is a very misleading wa of describing what's happening.  As you noticed yourself, it will already be zero inside the loop.

Comment: Of course ... simple mathematics!
Thank you very much.

PS: Thank you all for introducing me to SSCE

Comment: @kory: Glad to help.  The main point of writing a simple, self-contained example is, by the way, that it will usually help you to find your error yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't work because you don't declare an initial value for `foo1`, so you reference it without it existing - this will throw a `NameError`. If you do declare an initial value, the code will work:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> while True:
...    x += 1
...    if x > 10:
...        break
... 
>>> x
11
```

Not only that, but Python doesn't namespace in a while loop, so even if your code was modified to make y inside the while loop, it would still work:

```
>>> start = True
>>> while True:
...     if start:
...         y = 0
...         start = False
...     y += 1
...     if y > 10:
...         break
... 
>>> y
11
```

Note this is a very contrived example, and it's rare at best you actually want to do this.

Please give us a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/) which shows your code producing a result you do not want, along with the result you do want. As your problem simply doesn't exist in Python.

Comment: I will provide you my code. Probably my explanation is faulty :)

Comment: @kory: please see the link in the answer above.  In order to help, we need a `Self Contained` example showing your problem.  We can't all be expected to set up some local server on 20480, read German, have sqllite setup, etc, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare *foo1* before the loop

```
foo1 = 0
while True:
    fetch data
    foo1 = foo1 + 500
```

Variable *foo1* in your case had visibility scope only in *while* loop and when you used it out of loop it was just created again in global scope.

Comment: This is exactly what I did :)

Comment: @kory please, update your code how did you used it. The problem is defenitely in scoping of foo variable

Comment: @kory can provide your usage of your code, because if your code is like in question, it MUST work. if it's used in function, it's another question

Comment: This is not true. In Python, `while` loops do not have a separate namespace. You do not *need* to do this (although most of the time it makes far more sense to). -1.

Comment: Its definitely outside any functions as I havenÄt used any.

Comment: @Lattyware I meant that declared _foo1_ variable IN the while loop and than printed it in the outer scope

Comment: @Ribtoks Which you can do. Python doesn't scope `while` loops separately. If you create a variable in the scope of a `while` loop, it will 'leak' out into the global scope. See my answer, the second example.